# Moving text within a string to the end

Tags: r

Let's say I have strings like this:

```
PH&N 2015 LifeTime Series D
PH&N 2020 LifeTime Series D
PH&N 2025 LifeTime Series D
PH&N 2030 LifeTime Series D
PH&N 2035 LifeTime Series D
PH&N 2040 LifeTime Series D
PH&N 2045 LifeTime Series D
```

How would I move the numbers to the end like this, using R:

```
PH&N LifeTime Series D 2015
PH&N LifeTime Series D 2020
PH&N LifeTime Series D 2025
... and so on
```

A solution using gsub() would be preferable.

Comment: It doesn't use `gsub`, so I'll just leave this as a comment, but you could split on white space, and then `lapply` to reorder and paste the pieces back together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 gsub("([[:alpha:]]+\\s)([[:digit:]]+)\\s(.+)", "\\1\\3 \\2", dat2$V1)
```

[1] "PH&N LifeTime Series D2015 " "PH&N LifeTime Series D2020 " "PH&N LifeTime Series D2025 " "PH&N LifeTime Series D2030 " "PH&N LifeTime Series D2035 " "PH&N LifeTime Series D2040 "
[7] "PH&N LifeTime Series D2045 "

I see that Justin asked why his worked and the same Q applies to my solution. This would seem to be more correct:

```
gsub("([[:alpha:][:punct:]]+\\s)([[:digit:]]+)\\s(.+)", "\\1\\3 \\2", dat2$V1)
```

Comment: This does not have a space between "D" and the numeric part like the OP requested. (Also it has an extra space at the end)

Comment: That's not hard to fix. Jus move the \\s out of the middle target and add a space in the replacement string.

Answer (score 2):

dat <- read.tines('cliboard', sep=',')

```
gsub('([A-z]+) +([0-9]+) +(.+)$', '\\1 \\3 \\2', dat$V1)
```

not sure why the first group catches the & though...

Comment: @DWin interesting...  Your more explicit version is probably the "right" one.

Comment: I figured out that because neither of us used "^" that both of our patterns were matching "N\\s" rather than matching "PH&N\\s".

Answer (score 2):

```
 text <- c("PH&N 2015 LifeTime Series D",
 "PH&N 2020 LifeTime Series D",
 "PH&N 2025 LifeTime Series D",
 "PH&N 2030 LifeTime Series D",
 "PH&N 2035 LifeTime Series D",
 "PH&N 2040 LifeTime Series D",
 "PH&N 2045 LifeTime Series D")

> ans <- paste(gsub("[0-9]", "", text), as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", text)))
> gsub("  ", " ", ans) # replace the double space with a single space
[1] "PH&N LifeTime Series D 2015" "PH&N LifeTime Series D 2020"
[3] "PH&N LifeTime Series D 2025" "PH&N LifeTime Series D 2030"
[5] "PH&N LifeTime Series D 2035" "PH&N LifeTime Series D 2040"
[7] "PH&N LifeTime Series D 2045"
```

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen, 3 gsubs have got to be better than 1, right? ;-)